# Add a step to a reusable workflow in github-actions

Tags: github-actions

There is a reusable workflow github action i would like to add caching to.

Is it possible to add an additional step to this workflow, or do i need to update the workflow to add the step

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "update the workflow" ? You need to edit it and add next step to it, but I guess you meant something less obvious than that ?

Comment: Yeah. I would like to import that workflow from another repo, and append a step onto it, without updating the original workflow.

Comment: @MadmanLee really late, but any luck with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest reusable workflows, you can use nesting to add your customized jobs before or after the reusable workflow run. As of now, you can't add new steps unless you create your own copy of the workflow with default steps and your own steps.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a new step to the workflow by adding a new line to the `steps` section of the workflow file.

Comment: In this case i'm importing the workflow from another repo. So i can't update that workflow in that repo.